# MySQL Function for permutations of comma seperated string

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I need a query which can be used in (or as) a function and retrieves all combinations of n values. And I need all combinations of length k where k = 1..n.
Extended sample input and result so input has 3 values instead of 2 - however, number of input values may vary from 1 to n.

Example: Input: (Ann,John,Mark)

Output:  Ann,John,Mark,Ann John,John Mark,Ann Mark,Ann John Mark

Comment: Why not use php to create this function?